# Find integer $k$ such that $k \alpha_i \bmod{1}$ are simultaneously small for all $i$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

A classical result shows that if $\alpha$ is irrational, then $\{k \alpha \bmod{1}\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is dense over $[0,1]$.
Can we extend this result as follows?

> Suppose $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m$ are such that $(1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha_m)$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $k$ such that $k \alpha_i \bmod{1} \leq \varepsilon$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$.

Edit: it was originally asked assuming only that all $\alpha_i$ are irrational. As observed in the comments, for $m\ge 2$ and $\varepsilon<\frac12$, $\alpha_2=-\alpha_1$ yields an obvious counterexample.

Comment: Yes. This is because the infinite cyclic subgroup generated by $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m)$ in $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^m$ cannot be closed (since the latter is compact), and hence it accumulates at zero.

Comment: No. Check out $\alpha_1=1-\alpha_2=\sqrt3$. If you want the $k\alpha_i$ to be just close to integers (from either side) --- then yes, e.g., by the reasons @YCor mentions.

Comment: The answer is yes under the assumption that $1,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m$ are linearly independent, by Kronecker's theorem

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I maintain my positive answer. If the $\alpha_i$ are linearly dependent, it's not dense in the torus. But it still accumulates at zero. The case $m=2$, $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ is trivially equivalent to the case $m=1$.

Comment: My formula was different: $\alpha_1=\sqrt3$, but $\alpha_2=1-\sqrt3$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov doen't matter. If $k_i$ tends to infinity and $k_i\sqrt{3}$ tends to zero mod 1, then $k_i(1-\sqrt{3})$ also tends to zero mod 1.

Comment: @YCor: True, but from the other side, so you cannot tell $k\alpha_2\mod 1<\epsilon$. Both statements about  just accumulation in $0$ and one-sided accumulation in the linearly independent case are indeed true.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Ah, I see, I tend to work in the quotient (and hence interpreted as "$d(\alpha_i,\mathbf{Z})\le\varepsilon$"). Indeed taking the representative in $[0,1[$ yields a different conclusion. Given such a trivial counterexample I guess my interpretation was the OP's intent, so hopefully OP will clarify.

Comment: If the $\alpha$'s are linearly independent, you even get an asymptotic formula for the number of $k$'s for which your inequality holds, by Weyl's equidistribution result.

Comment: Lwins, can you participate in the discussion and clarify your question?

Comment: @YCor I think I prefer adding the constraint that all $a_i$’s and $1$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Then please edit your post accordingly.

Comment: @YCor I don't think it is necessary. Changing the OP may make other readers be confused on the constraint (since some comments are based on the original constraint).

Comment: It's necessary. I've done so, adding the context which makes the comments understandable.

Answer (score 2):

(reflecting the comments)

The answer is yes, by Kronecker's theorem. Namely, the assumption that $(1,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m)$ is linearly independent over $\mathbf{Q}$ means that $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m)$ generates a dense sub(semi)group of the torus $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^m$, and hence this subsemigroup meets $[0,\varepsilon]^m$ (infinitely many times).

In the original setting (assuming only $\alpha_i$ irrational for some $i$), it is still true that it meets $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]^m$ infinitely many times: indeed this assumption ensures that the closure of the sub(semi)group is non-discrete and accumulates at zero. (And using that every nonempty closed subsemigroup of a compact group is a subgroup.) But for $m\ge 2$, taking $\alpha_2=-\alpha_1$ irrational shows that it doesn't work with $[0,\varepsilon]^m$ instead.